# Zabbix cannot monitor SQL after changing service account

Tags: powershell, zabbix

I monitor SQL Server with Zabbix, the template gets information with powershell:

```
powershell Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_MSSQLServer_SQLServerDatabases
```

I changed the account from SQL account to a Windows Account for running the service, after this Zabbix cannot receive information anymore.

Comment: I Monitor SQL Server with Zabbix,Zabbix template get information from sql server with powershell script,
Later i changed account from sql account to windows account for run service,After changed,Zabbix cannot recive information

Comment: Questons about Zabbix should be on SuperUser not Stackoverflow, voting to move question.

Comment: In Administration → Authentication the user authentication method to Zabbix can be changed. The available methods are internal, LDAP and HTTP authentication.